# MySql error log location

Tags: magento2, database, log

I'm using Magento 2 and would like to know where the log files are for mysql. Are they inside my main magento folder or are they elsewhere. I know that the main log files for magento are in `var/log` but I cannot seem to find the mysql errors. ]

Reason I'm looking is to solve:

`>[2018-09-17 20:59:51] main.ERROR: MySQL connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory [] []`

Comment: That means your mysql is not running . please restart wamp or xamp or apache2 etc

Comment: Re install the server. Then only it will work

Comment: I've had this issue with 2 fresh copies of Magento 2 now. After about 2 weeks of smooth running, the servers seem to crash daily. If you are knowledgeable on this matter, i encourage you to view my other question on this topic: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/242667/magento-2-site-crashing-after-2-weeks-believed-cron-or-mysql-problem

Answer (score 1):

Hey can you check your mysql server is running or not because your magento 2 is unable to create connection to your mysql and also check which database you mention in app/etc env.php file.

Comment: I've restarted my server and everything seems fine now. Recently, my server has been crashing daily and i'm not sure why. This is my log

Comment: Please mark as solution if it works for you .also share your log so that we can dig up the issue.

Comment: My question was about the location of mysql log files. Do you know where they are located?  I posted a question earlier that includes the log: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/242667/magento-2-site-crashing-after-2-weeks-believed-cron-or-mysql-problem

Comment: No In my knowledge if any mysql error comes then it always  go to exception.log . it won't generate separate  log file for  Mysql errors.
You can find exception.log here:- var/log/exception.log